# Probability of separation of points on a sphere

Tags: probability, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

I distribute $N$ points on a sphere according to

$\displaystyle  \theta=\arccos(2u-1) \\
\phi = 2\pi v      $

where $\theta$ is the zonal angle, $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle, and $u$ and $v$ are random variables ranging uniformly from 0 to 1.  All this to say, I am distributing so that points will not be more highly concentrated at the $\theta$ poles than at the equator.

Now, I do this for $N$ points.  Given some angular separation $\Omega$, what is the probability that there will be some pair of points separated from each other by less than $\Omega$?

(Please don't ask me to show my work.  I don't even know where to begin!)

Comment: For a *random* distribution of points on a sphere, the cumulative distribution function for the separation of a pair of points goes as $(1 - \cos \Omega)/2$.  Since your points are more concentrated than a random distribution, perhaps that function could be used to at least give you a lower bound on the probability?  That's the function for a single pair, so you'd have to fold in the fact that you have $N(N-1)/2$ pairs of points.